# How to get last 7 days from mongodb using timestamp?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am using mongodb.In my events collection data stored like this
[events collection schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciswR.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciswR.jpg)

I tried with this, but i am not getting any documents.

```
db.events.find({community:ObjectId("5e57a29950045a54c62aa729"),type:"join",status:"completed",ts: 
{"$gt":"timestamp(1582337058,0)"}})
```

Now i need last 7days data from current timestamp. How can i write the query?

Answer (score 0):

just make sure you know
mongodb shell support full JavaScript
so here is my solution

```
db.events.find({community:ObjectId("5e57a29950045a54c62aa729"),type:"join",status:"completed",ts: 
{"$gt":"new Date().getTime()-604800000"}})
```

there must be more clever way to write these js,but this will work.
Hope this solve your problem

↑ turns out i understanding wrong of the problem
↓ this is right solution incase other people run into same issue

```
db.events.find({community:ObjectId("5e57a29950045a54c62aa729"),type:"join",status:"completed",ts: 
{"$gt":Timestamp(1582337058,0)}})
```

Comment: thanks for your response. "new Date().getTime()-604800000" this is converted to timestamp and more over this differentiate not working in mongodb shell

Comment: because in mongodb ts fields stored with timestamp is different than regular timestamp

Comment: @RameshReddy  maybe try this {"$gt":Timestamp(1582337058,0)}  remove the ""

Answer (score 0):

For my `pymongo` code, here's what I found to work:

```
import datetime
a_time_before = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=45)
params = {'created_at': {"$gte": a_time_before}}
mydb.mytable.find(params)
```